# Spring Integration SFTP Outbound Gateway replace file

Tags: spring, spring-integration

What is wrong with this Config ? I am not able to overwrite an existing file in the sftp server location (new and old file name are the same). the directory has 777 as chmod too. I have added the error logs below. I have attached the atmoz dockercompose file for you to analyze this issue.

```
     @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "toSftpChannel")
    public MessageHandler toSftpChannelHandler() {
        SftpOutboundGateway sftpOutboundGateway =
                new SftpOutboundGateway(
                        sftpDestinationSessionFactory(),
                        AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Command.PUT.getCommand(),
                        "headers['remote-target-dir']");
        sftpOutboundGateway.setRemoteDirectoryExpression(PARSER.parseExpression("headers['remote-target-dir']"));
        sftpOutboundGateway.setUseTemporaryFileName(true);
         sftpOutboundGateway.setTemporaryFileSuffix(".temp");
        sftpOutboundGateway.setFileExistsMode(FileExistsMode.REPLACE);
        sftpOutboundGateway.setOutputChannelName("deleteLocalFilesChannel");
        sftpOutboundGateway.setAdviceChain(List.of(retryAdvice));
        return sftpOutboundGateway;
    }
```

```
file_remoteFile=SampleIntegrationFile.txt, timestamp=1675720242276}]
2023-02-07T07:55:18.854+10:00  INFO 9752 --- [   scheduling-1] c.d.s.sftpTosftp.middle.ProcessMessage   : Input File Path: C:\tmp\sftp-inbound\sftpToSftpData\SampleIntegrationFile.txt
2023-02-07T07:55:18.854+10:00  INFO 9752 --- [   scheduling-1] c.d.s.sftpTosftp.middle.ProcessMessage   : Input File Headers: [file_remoteHostPort=localhost:22, file_name=SampleIntegrationFile.txt, file_remoteDirectory=//sftp/Outgoing/sftpToSftp/, file_originalFile=\tmp\sftp-inbound\sftpToSftpData\SampleIntegrationFile.txt, id=35841395-ac31-6636-966c-fc3cc0d04329, file_relativePath=SampleIntegrationFile.txt, file_remoteFile=SampleIntegrationFile.txt, timestamp=1675720518854]
2023-02-07T07:55:18.854+10:00 DEBUG 9752 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Retry: count=0
2023-02-07T07:55:21.891+10:00 DEBUG 9752 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Checking for rethrow: count=1
2023-02-07T07:55:21.891+10:00 DEBUG 9752 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Retry: count=1
2023-02-07T07:55:21.916+10:00  WARN 9752 --- []-nio2-thread-2] o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier     : Server at localhost/127.0.0.1:22 presented unverified RSA key: SHA256:kQ7FBDG5+ZBmGHEsYW4RQmhmKHptYsN0MsAeQ7Cx1So
2023-02-07T07:55:22.014+10:00  WARN 9752 --- [-nio2-thread-13] o.a.s.c.session.ClientConnectionService  : globalRequest(ClientConnectionService[ClientSessionImpl[admin@localhost/127.0.0.1:22]])[hostkeys-00@openssh.com, want-reply=false] failed (SshException) to process: EdDSA provider not supported
2023-02-07T07:55:25.250+10:00 DEBUG 9752 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Checking for rethrow: count=2
2023-02-07T07:55:25.250+10:00 DEBUG 9752 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Retry: count=2
2023-02-07T07:55:25.271+10:00  WARN 9752 --- []-nio2-thread-4] o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier     : Server at localhost/127.0.0.1:22 presented unverified RSA key: SHA256:kQ7FBDG5+ZBmGHEsYW4RQmhmKHptYsN0MsAeQ7Cx1So
2023-02-07T07:55:25.327+10:00  WARN 9752 --- [-nio2-thread-13] o.a.s.c.session.ClientConnectionService  : globalRequest(ClientConnectionService[ClientSessionImpl[admin@localhost/127.0.0.1:22]])[hostkeys-00@openssh.com, want-reply=false] failed (SshException) to process: EdDSA provider not supported
2023-02-07T07:55:28.561+10:00 DEBUG 9752 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Checking for rethrow: count=3
2023-02-07T07:55:28.561+10:00 DEBUG 9752 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Retry: count=3
2023-02-07T07:55:28.584+10:00  WARN 9752 --- []-nio2-thread-8] o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier     : Server at localhost/127.0.0.1:22 presented unverified RSA key: SHA256:kQ7FBDG5+ZBmGHEsYW4RQmhmKHptYsN0MsAeQ7Cx1So
2023-02-07T07:55:28.683+10:00  WARN 9752 --- [-nio2-thread-13] o.a.s.c.session.ClientConnectionService  : globalRequest(ClientConnectionService[ClientSessionImpl[admin@localhost/127.0.0.1:22]])[hostkeys-00@openssh.com, want-reply=false] failed (SshException) to process: EdDSA provider not supported
2023-02-07T07:55:31.958+10:00 DEBUG 9752 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Checking for rethrow: count=4
2023-02-07T07:55:31.958+10:00 DEBUG 9752 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Retry: count=4
2023-02-07T07:55:31.979+10:00  WARN 9752 --- [-nio2-thread-10] o.a.s.c.k.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier     : Server at localhost/127.0.0.1:22 presented unverified RSA key: SHA256:kQ7FBDG5+ZBmGHEsYW4RQmhmKHptYsN0MsAeQ7Cx1So
2023-02-07T07:55:32.072+10:00  WARN 9752 --- [-nio2-thread-13] o.a.s.c.session.ClientConnectionService  : globalRequest(ClientConnectionService[ClientSessionImpl[admin@localhost/127.0.0.1:22]])[hostkeys-00@openssh.com, want-reply=false] failed (SshException) to process: EdDSA provider not supported
2023-02-07T07:55:32.315+10:00 DEBUG 9752 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Checking for rethrow: count=5
2023-02-07T07:55:32.315+10:00 DEBUG 9752 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Retry failed last attempt: count=5
2023-02-07T07:55:32.318+10:00 ERROR 9752 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to handle, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=\tmp\sftp-inbound\sftpToSftpData\SampleIntegrationFile.txt, headers={file_remoteHostPort=localhost:22, file_name=SampleIntegrationFile.txt, file_remoteDirectory=//sftp/Outgoing/sftpToSftp/, remote-target-dir=/sftp/Incoming/sftpToSftp/, file_originalFile=\tmp\sftp-inbound\sftpToSftpData\SampleIntegrationFile.txt, id=cd33b5fa-4fab-93c3-d46a-5955f858ce0a, file_relativePath=\tmp\sftp-inbound\sftpToSftpData\SampleIntegrationFile.txt, file_remoteFile=SampleIntegrationFile.txt, timestamp=1675720518854}]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice$CallbackImpl.cloneAndExecute(AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice.java:175)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerRetryAdvice.lambda$doInvoke$1(RequestHandlerRetryAdvice.java:86)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:329)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:255)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerRetryAdvice.doInvoke(RequestHandlerRetryAdvice.java:86)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice.invoke(AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice.java:67)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:218)
    at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy60.handleRequestMessage(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.doInvokeAdvisedRequestHandler(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:155)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:139)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.doHandleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.sendInternal(AbstractMessageChannel.java:373)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:327)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:297)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:484)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.doProduceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:339)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:268)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:232)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:142)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.doHandleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.sendInternal(AbstractMessageChannel.java:373)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:327)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:297)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.handleMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:196)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.messageReceived(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:474)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:460)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.pollForMessage(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:412)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$createPoller$4(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:348)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$createPoller$5(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:341)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:96)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Error handling message for file [C:\tmp\sftp-inbound\sftpToSftpData\SampleIntegrationFile.txt -> SampleIntegrationFile.txt], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=\tmp\sftp-inbound\sftpToSftpData\SampleIntegrationFile.txt, headers={file_remoteHostPort=localhost:22, file_name=SampleIntegrationFile.txt, file_remoteDirectory=//sftp/Outgoing/sftpToSftp/, remote-target-dir=/sftp/Incoming/sftpToSftp/, file_originalFile=\tmp\sftp-inbound\sftpToSftpData\SampleIntegrationFile.txt, id=cd33b5fa-4fab-93c3-d46a-5955f858ce0a, file_relativePath=\tmp\sftp-inbound\sftpToSftpData\SampleIntegrationFile.txt, file_remoteFile=SampleIntegrationFile.txt, timestamp=1675720518854}]
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.doSend(RemoteFileTemplate.java:367)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.lambda$send$0(RemoteFileTemplate.java:314)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:452)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.send(RemoteFileTemplate.java:314)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.send(RemoteFileTemplate.java:302)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.put(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.java:831)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.lambda$doPut$13(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.java:817)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.invoke(RemoteFileTemplate.java:484)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.doPut(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.java:816)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.doPut(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.java:812)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.handleRequestMessage(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.java:589)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler$AdvisedRequestHandler.handleRequestMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:208)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice$CallbackImpl.cloneAndExecute(AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice.java:166)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to write to '/sftp/Incoming/sftpToSftp/SampleIntegrationFile.txt.temp' while uploading the file
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.sendFileToRemoteDirectory(RemoteFileTemplate.java:573)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.doSend(RemoteFileTemplate.java:353)
    ... 77 more
Caused by: SFTP error (SSH_FX_FAILURE): Failure
    at org.apache.sshd.sftp.client.impl.AbstractSftpClient.throwStatusException(AbstractSftpClient.java:217)
    at org.apache.sshd.sftp.client.impl.AbstractSftpClient.checkResponseStatus(AbstractSftpClient.java:212)
    at org.apache.sshd.sftp.client.impl.AbstractSftpClient.checkResponseStatus(AbstractSftpClient.java:186)
    at org.apache.sshd.sftp.client.impl.AbstractSftpClient.checkCommandStatus(AbstractSftpClient.java:164)
    at org.apache.sshd.sftp.client.impl.AbstractSftpClient.rename(AbstractSftpClient.java:647)
    at org.apache.sshd.sftp.client.SftpClient.rename(SftpClient.java:617)
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.rename(SftpSession.java:162)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory$CachedSession.rename(CachingSessionFactory.java:252)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.doSend(RemoteFileTemplate.java:606)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.sendFileToRemoteDirectory(RemoteFileTemplate.java:570)
```

[My Atmoz dockercompose file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2izFz.png)

Comment: What version are you using? Do you see any logs like "Failed to delete..."? Show the full stack trace (edit the question, don't try to put it in a comment).

Comment: I am using the latest version 6.0 spring integration with java sdk 17

Comment: Ignore my last comment; the `SftpSession` automatically falls back to delete if the rename fails with `SSH_FX_FILE_ALREADY_EXISTS`. Looks like some other, generic, error on the server `SSH_FX_FAILURE` - maybe your user doesn't have rename privileges, or the server is returning the wrong error? Take a look at the server logs to see if there are clues there.

Comment: I am using the admin user with 777 chmod for directory that I am trying to upload to. The docker sftp server container image is Atmoz/sftp.

Comment: Any chances to know an error on the server side? What version of SFTP do you use though?

Comment: I have added the docker compose file image for your reference.

Comment: I am able to add file, delete file, modify the file with chmod 777 on directory, but not rename. Not sure if this is a spring library issue or not, because in the older version of spring integration < 6.0 with the same atmoz server config i can overwrite the files with the above config.

Comment: I think there should be some log on that SFTP server to point us to the reason behind this error. May be your existing file is opened somewhere?..

Comment: I suspect the most likely problem is the server is returning a non-specific error instead of the `SSH_FX_FILE_ALREADY_EXISTS`. The older SI versions uses a different SSH client and deletes the file for any exception on the rename (which is why it works there) - whereas with the new client, it only falls back to delete for the specific error - @ArtemBilan - perhaps that should be reconsidered and reinstate the previous behavior?

Comment: Sure! We can do that. Feel free to raise a GH issue and PR the fix.

Comment: I can confirm with extensive testing, spring integration <6.0 allows renaming of the files if the file already exists, but 6.0 does not, same atmoz sftp was used in both.

Comment: If you want to try the fix I suggested, clone the spring-integration repo; change this https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/e6d0a4f826164e0da6c440afb63533dab15e0abd/spring-integration-sftp/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/sftp/session/SftpSession.java#L165-L172 to remove the if test (unconditionally execute the `remove()` after any exception). Then `./gradlew :spring-integration-sftp:check` then `./gradlew :spring-integration-sftp:publishToMavenLocal`, then use `spring-integration-sftp` version `6.0.3-SNAPSHOT`. Requires Java 17.

Comment: Just to follow up, `SSH_FX_FILE_ALREADY_EXISTS = 11` `File already exists.` whereas `SSH_FX_FAILURE=4` `Generic failure. An unknown error occurred.`. So, it does look like your atmoz server is either incorrectly returning a generic error instead of the specific error, or some other error has occurred. I suspect the former, but testing the fix will confirm that. See https://docs.oracle.com/en/industries/communications/eagle/46.9/commands-error-recovery/eagle-ftp-sftp-ssh-error-codes.html and https://winscp.net/eng/docs/sftp_codes

Comment: The second link even says `An error occurred, but no specific error code exists to describe the failure. This error message should always have meaningful text in the the error message field.`